# Vuetify - navigation drawer mini variant replacing icon on click

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

**EDIT**

**I found a solution:**

```
<v-icon>
  {{ mini ? 'mdi-chevron-right' : 'mdi-chevron-left' }}
</v-icon>
```

Is it possible to change the icon when switching navigation drawer variant? The default variant should have the **mdi-chevron-left** icon, and when I switch to the mini variant the icon should change to **mdi-chevron-right**. Can I do something like this? I can't find information on this anywhere.

Full working demo code [here](https://codepen.io/noobmaster2137/pen/XWNQOYE)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar
      color="primary"
      dense
      dark
    >
      
      <v-btn
          icon
          @click.stop="mini = !mini"
          class="mr-2"
      >
        <v-icon>mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
      </v-btn>

      <v-toolbar-title>Page title</v-toolbar-title>

    </v-app-bar>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      class="deep-purple accent-4"
      dark
      permanent
      v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant="mini"
    >
      <v-list>
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            link
          >
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
  
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
  
      <template v-slot:append>
        <div class="pa-2">
          <v-btn block>
            <v-icon left>mdi-logout</v-icon>
            Logout
          </v-btn>
        </div>
      </template>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      drawer: null,
      mini: false,
      items: [
        { title: 'Dashboard', icon: 'mdi-view-dashboard' },
        { title: 'Account', icon: 'mdi-account-box' },
        { title: 'Admin', icon: 'mdi-gavel' },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. We can create a computed variable (`appBarIcon` in this example) that will check if "this.mini" is either true or false, then showing the right icon for it.

```html
<v-icon>{{ appBarIcon }}</v-icon>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    ...
  },

  // Create a computed variable for our app bar icon
  computed: {
    appBarIcon() {
      return this.mini ? "mdi-chevron-right" : "mdi-chevron-left";
    },
  }

})
```

Working [demo at codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-franklin-0lc4q?file=/src/App.vue:1319-1427).

[image]